# I took part in Tezos ICO in 2017, but I do not know the site where my coins from ICO are now

Tags: wallets

Please help me!
I took part in Tezos ICO in 2017,  but I do not know the site where my coins from ICO are now. Where is this site now? What is its name?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "site where my coins from ICO are now". Blockchain 101: Coins live on the chain, not in any wallet nor on any website. Wallets and websites are just visual interfaces to the chain. This is true for every crypto type.

From the ICO, you should have received a PDF with your email and a private key. If you have this PDF and the key, you can import this key to *any* wallet and access your ICO funds.

If you don't have that PDF and the private key, then you've lost it all.

Answer (score 0):

By Tezos ICO I assume you mean the Tezos Fundraiser. The process of claiming a fundraiser allocation can be broken down into 2 main steps.

1. [Activate](https://tezos.com/learn/activate/) the allocation (requires KYC)
2. Import the fundraiser account into a Tezos wallet of your choice

To complete these steps you will need some information that you received when you participated. You can find that information in a PDF file that you should have downloaded and stored safely, without which it will be impossible to claim your allocation.

From that PDF file (which should look similar to [this](https://check.tezos.com/img/temp/temp-public_key.jpg)) you will need:

- Your Public Key Hash (commonly called Tezos address, starts with tz1)
- The email address that you provided during the fundraiser
- The 15 word secret key (do *not* reveal this to anyone)

You will also need a password which you provided during the fundraiser process. Unfortunately this password is not included in the PDF (you should have memorized it). If you cannot remember the password, I suggest you try different passwords, and failing that, you may try the official [password recovery tool](https://recovery.tezos.com/).

If you plan to keep your tez, remember to delegate your tez account so that you can start earning baking rewards. It's also highly recommended that you use a hardware wallet (like a Ledger) for any long-term storage.